# If $\nu$ is a Levy measure, how to show that $\nu( (-\epsilon,\epsilon)^c ) <\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning, upper-lower-bounds, levy-processes

We know that the Levy measure on borelians is a measure $\nu$ such that
\begin{equation}
    \int \frac{|x|^2}{1+ |x|^2} \nu (dx) < \infty
\end{equation}
We can show that this is  equivalent to:
\begin{equation}
    \nu(\{0\}),\quad \int_{|x|<1}|x|^{2} \nu (dx) <\infty, \quad \int_{|x| \geq 1}  \nu (dx)<\infty. 
\end{equation}

So I am interested to show that
$$\nu( (-\epsilon,\epsilon)^c )< \infty, \quad \forall \epsilon, \,\,  0< \epsilon < 1.$$.

Notice that
$$\nu( (-\epsilon,\epsilon)^c ) = \int_{[|x|> \epsilon]}\nu(dx)= \int_{\mathbb R}  \chi_{[|x|> \epsilon]} \nu(dx) $$

From here, I'm failing to show the integral is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\nu((-\epsilon,\epsilon)^{c})= \nu((-1,1)^{c})+\int_{\epsilon \leq |x| < 1}\nu (dx)$$ and $$\int_{\epsilon \leq |x| < 1}\nu (dx)\leq \frac 1 {\epsilon^{2}}\int_{\epsilon \leq |x| < 1}|x|^{2}\nu (dx)\leq \frac 1 {\epsilon^{2}}\int_{|x| < 1}|x|^{2}\nu (dx)$$